# Can an xpage use the authentication from the notes client?

Tags: xpages

I have a Xpages application which requires authentication. 
When I open this xpage application in the notes client (integrated webbrowser) I also have to authenticate. Is there a way that I don't have to authenticate when the xpage is opened in the client. So ,is there a way that the xpage can use the authentication from the notes client ?

Comment: I think XPiNC does what you are looking for. If you need to use browser, SSO is what you need.

Comment: Perhaps this answer to a related question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13367562/785061

Comment: First :Is it correct that SSO (SPNEGO) will only work on a windows server? We are running on linux. Second : Non xpnic users should be able to connect also through internet. Is that also possible with SSO ?

Comment: If it helps, the question is not specific to XPages. The authentication isn't handled by the XPages runtime but by the Domino HTTP server. So the key is how to authenticate to Domino via a URL link from Notes Client.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for the Notes internal web browser to pick up the user's credentials from the Notes log in.. However it might be possible to use the accounts API to do what you need.. You can add an account via Notes Preferences->Accounts.. Create a new HTTP account. I believe (but am not 100% certain) that the credentials defined in the account will be used.. I am not 100% sure of this, but worth a shot!